# assign higher header level to pandas data frame in the read_csv command

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am reading multiple csv files into pandas and concatenating them into one frame. Each csv file shape is 8x256. I am using the following code:

```
path = r'may12_fm'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv'))
df_may= pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in all_files ), ignore_index=True, axis=1,)
```

I want to keep the name of each file as a higher level header, and also the lower header numbering to be from 0 to 255 for all concatenated frames, something like this:

--- m_0  -----------------            m_1  --------------        m_3
--- 0  1  2   3   4  .... 255  ----   0, 1, 2, ...255------      0, 1, 2, .....255
0
1
2
3
4
...

I appreciate helping me in this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the files names used, and (if) you know the number of columns per file, maybe you could just do it after the files are loaded.

**Example frame**

```
   0  1  2  0  1  2
0  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4  4  4
```

**What this answer assumes you know**

```
all_files = ['m_0','m_1']
cols_per_file = 3
```

**Then you could build a multi-index**

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.repeat(all_files, cols_per_file), df.columns])
print(idx) 

MultiIndex([('m_0', 0),
            ('m_0', 1),
            ('m_0', 2),
            ('m_1', 0),
            ('m_1', 1),
            ('m_1', 2)],
           )
```

**And then assign back to the frame**

```
df.columns = idx
print(df)
```

**Result**

```
  m_0       m_1      
    0  1  2   0  1  2
0   1  1  1   1  1  1
1   2  2  2   2  2  2
2   3  3  3   3  3  3
3   4  4  4   4  4  4
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the trick. however, for some reason, the numbers goes all the way from 0 to the end of the frame instead of repeating in cycles of 0..255. Do you have  any idea why this is happening or if there is another way to do it? thanks

Comment: I think  `ignore_index=True` is messing you up.   With that `The resulting axis will be labeled 0, …, n - 1.`

Comment: That is correct. when i changed it to False the numbers worked out. Thanks a lot.